# Using VBA code to sort through start and end dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am working on some code that requires me to

1. Remove all duplicate iterations of a task
2. Pick the earliest start date and latest end date for each iteration of each task

[On the left hand side you can see what my data looks like, and on the right hand side is what I would like it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cou2N.png)

I think i can get the code to leave only unique values for each task#, but I can't think of a way to get the earliest start date and latest end date for each task.

As you can see, because of how the data was pulled, there are some null values for task #, which do not matter and need to be tossed out as well.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the start and end date, then you can use formulas straight on your worksheet without using VBA. You can combine `MIN` and `IF` functions to find the start date, then `MAX` and `IF` to find the end date.

**To find start date**

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$B$17=G6,$C$2:$C$17))
```

**To find end date**

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$17=G6,$D$2:$D$17))
```

[image]

**Edit:**
I have made some adjustments to the formulae based on @Yorik's input on the comments that in case of multiple projects, the tasks' dates will be the same although the projects are different. To find the unique/distinct project and tasks, use the `UNIQUE` function. IT will shows the results on 2 columns.

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B22)
```

[image]

Then on the adjacent columns, enter the formulae below. It will check the projects and tasks, then get the start and end dates. For dates that are null, the cells will be left blank.

**To Find the start date**

```
=IF(G7<>0,MIN(IF($B$2:$B$22=G7,IF($A$2:$A$22=F7,C$2:$C$22))),"")
```

**To Find the start date**

```
=IF(G7<>0,MAX(IF($B$2:$B$22=G7,IF($A$2:$A$22=F7,C$2:$C$22))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: At first glance, this looks like it might aggregate on e.g. all "task #1" even when that "task #1" is "Project #2". (?)

Comment: @Yorik I have only done the part of finding the dates as OP has shown only Project #1 on the image posted. If there are more projects. The formulae must be modified.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, Thank you for your reply, but I do not have access to the unique function.

Comment: @KeithMiller I guess you don't use Excel 365. It is among the new functions introduced las year. I will try to change the formula with more conventional functions when I have time during the next hours. I will edit the answer when done.

Comment: @KeithMiller It just got too messy when I tried to find with other functions to give the same results that UNIQUE function. Maybe you can try to modified formula and macro code from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128581/index-multiple-columns-and-match-distinct-values-returning-list-of-unique-value